# PropertyNamingStrategy ignored when using @JsonAnyGetter

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-boot

**Scenario:**

Using Jackson 2.4.5 I have a dynamic bean to be serialised into JSON which can store some of its state in 'optional' properties in an internal map and uses `@JsonAnyGetter` on an accessor method that returns this map, e.g:

```
public class DynamicJsonView {

private final Map<String, Object> optionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

private final String rqdProperty = "blah";

public String getRqdProperty() {
    return rqdProperty;
}

public DynamicJsonView() {
    optionalProperties.put("PROP_1", "value 1");
    optionalProperties.put("PROP_2", "value 2");
    optionalProperties.put("PROP_3", "value 3");
    // etc - in reality populated from another map
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> any() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(optionalProperties);
} 
}
```

Note the map keys are UPPER_CASE.  When we setup our `ObjectMapper` we set the following naming strategy to convert properties to lower case (and replace camelCase with snake_case), e.g:

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

**Problem:**

This works exactly as expected with normal java properties, i.e. `rqdProperty` in the example above converts to `rqd_property` in the JSON serialized form, but the naming strategy is seemingly ignored for the map 'properties', with the upper case keys appearing unmodified. Having debugged the jackson `LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy#translate` method and watched the `input` parameter values passed in as the object is serialised, it seems the keys are never passed through the naming strategy.

The obvious workaround is to pre-process the map keys and convert them all to lower case, but I wondered if there's something I'm missing with regards to the property naming strategy, or if this is simply a limitation of the library?

Answer (score 1):

This is as designed since `NamingStrategy` is only applied to actual concrete properties, and not for `Map` keys, or "any" properties.

But if ability to include name mangling for any properties sounds like a good idea, you could request a new feature to do that: it could be enabled (for example) by a flag of `@JsonAnySetter`:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/

Comment: thanks @StaxMan , I've worked round it for now but will consider requesting a new feature.